# Why does Ubuntu use both systemd and init?

Tags: init, systemd

Many distros adopted systemd and left init why does Ubuntu still use init?

Comment: Last I heard, the transition fully to systemd was slated for soem way through the 15.04 dev cycle, but that may have just been rumor

Comment: I'm just wondering why not directly endorse systemd? Isn't it better that init?

Comment: Ubuntu is in transition from Unity to systemd. Debian has not fully implimented systemd yet. Fedora is one that uses systemd as much as any, and fedora still uses init .See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd . There are a ever decreasing number of boot scripts that still use init scripts

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Don't you mean Upstart instead of Unity?

Comment: Question does not make sense.  systemd is *is* (an) `init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there has been no additional movement on `systemd` vs. `upstart` vs `System V Init` in the mailing lists for 15.04.  There was a summit meeting on this during the last Ubuntu Online Summit for developers, as seen [here](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1411/meeting/22401/systemd-transition/).  As far as I am aware, that was the last set of discussion on the issue.  It is likely there has not been any further movement on the issue since then.

Also, some discussion-point notes can be found on here: http://pad.ubuntu.com/uos-1411-systemd-transition  (but you'll need a Launchpad account that has access to the etherpad to view this).

> Please note: Your question is designed to inspire a discussion, rather than a clear answer.  Such questions and answers are outside the scope of this site, which is designed to provide clear questions and answers.  If you wish to inspire further discussion, you may consider emailing the Development mailing lists, or try posting on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) instead.)

Comment: You mean `systemd` vs `upstart` right?  Both are different forms of init.

Comment: @psusi yes, however I was quoting the OP at the time.